# PHP + ODBC + FreeTDS + MSSQL: Can't change TDS version

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, freetds

I have PHP/ODBC/FreeTDS set up to connect my Ubuntu host to a remote MSSQL instance, which technically works. I can execute simple queries just fine. However, I can't use prepared statements; which yield the following error:

> Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver
>   does not support this function, SQL state IM001 in
>   SQLDescribeParameter...

I'm guessing that's because an early TDS version (4.2) is being used, which doesn't support prepared statements and other things. The trouble is, I can't seem to change the TDS version being used! I've tried all the configurations I can think of...

Running `tsql -C` yields:

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
```

Notice "`TDS version: 4.2`", despite the following configuration.

**odbc.ini**

```
[db_dsn]
Driver      = FreeTDS
Servername  = mssql_server
Database    = my_database
Description = My MSSQL database.
Trace       = No
```

**odbcinst.ini**

```
[FreeTDS]
Description     = TDS connection
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
FileUsage       = 1
```

**freetds.conf**

```
[global]
    tds version = 7.2
    text size = 64512

[mssql_server]
    host = <IP>
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.2
```

**PHP**

```
$connection = odbc_connect('db_dsn', $username, $password);
$statement = odbc_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (? ?)");
$exec = odbc_execute($statement, array($val1, $val2));
```

I've tried setting the `TDSVER` environment variable and also running `tsql -C --with-tdsver=7.0`, with no effect (not even in the `tsql -C` output). I also tried specifying a matching `TDS_Version` for the DSN in `odbc.ini` and using `Server` and `Port` in `odbc.ini` instead of `Servername` to declare that stuff in `freetds.conf`.

None of those changes seemed to change the reported TDS version or the resulting SQL error I mentioned above. I am sure that I'm editing the correct `freetds.conf` file at `/etc/freetds`, and I know my DSN works because I can do simple `SELECT` statements, etc.

Can anyone tell me what I'm overlooking or what I'm missing here? I'm sure it's some little thing, but I just can't see it.

---

**Edit #1:**
Changed configured TDS version from 7.0 to 7.2.

**Edit #2:**
As per Flipper's comment, I added the duplicate `Port` and `TDS_Version` info to my `odbc.ini` DSN as well as `freetds.conf` (no change):

```
[db_dsn]
Driver      = FreeTDS
Servername  = mssql_server
Port        = 1433
TDS_Version = 7.2
Database    = my_database
Description = My MSSQL database.
Trace       = No
```

Comment: Is your `freetds.conf` in `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`? It seems it is default for 4.2 because it can't find your freetds.conf. For odbc.ini, try adding port `Port = 1433` and `TDS_Version = 7.0`. Also, since you're on FreeTDS v0.91, if you're on SQL Server >= 2005, I'd recommend using TDS Version 7.2.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on TDS version; I've changed my configuration to 7.2 (see edit #1).

Comment: I am sure the correct `/etc/freetds/freeds.conf` is being used, as I can do a simple `SELECT` when that's the only place host and port are declared. If I change `host` in `freetds.conf` to the wrong IP, the `SELECT` fails. If I change it back, it succeeds. Regardless, I've added `Port` and `TDS_Version` to my DSN in `odbc.ini` in case there's some reason the info needs to be in both places (see edit #2), but no joy.

Comment: I mainly use Python, but let's try something else. Can you try a connection string in PHP like this: `$connection = odbc_connect("Driver=FreeTDS;Server=some.server.com;Port=1433;Database=my_database;TDS_Version=7.2;", $username, $password);` I believe you may have to use an in-line DSN. I'm still puzzled by why it is seeing v4.2 in the `tsql -C`, but this is worth a try. Also, in your freetds.conf, try appending `dump file = /tmp/freetds.log` and `dump file append = yes`; this will give you a more robust log when running to `tail`.

Comment: I get exactly the same error when I use your connection string instead of my DSN. Something is really fishy here...